# Problem with SQL Server ManageMent Studio Intellisense

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have problem with autocompletion in MSSMS 2008. Every time when I try to write simple 'Id' column MSSMS replace it with 'IDENTITY' (because IDENTITY is first entry that starts on letter I).

I found that entries in autocompletion dropdown aren't sorted correctly, so I have:

entries starting on letter I:

```
IDENTITY  
...  
ISNULL  
...  
ICQNumber  
..  
Id
```

Is there any way to change this wrong behaviour to correct one? I mean - force MSSMS 2008 to sort it correctly?

Comment: It's stuff like this that is why I turned it off. I can usually type what I want faster than I can fix the broken intellisense. Plus it intereferes with my flow of thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I've found (and it's a good practice anyhow) is to start column references with the table name (or alias):

```
SELECT YourTable.id
    FROM YourTable
```

OR

```
SELECT yt.id
    FROM YourTable yt
```

Comment: Even when I preface my column with a table alias, SSMS STILL replaces "yt.id" with "yt.IDENTITY"

Comment: @Shock That is a known issue in SQL Server 2008. It is fixed in 2012.

Answer (score 10):

It seems that Intellisense has some case sensitivity going on.

Typing either `id` or `ID` causes it to prompt `IDENTITY` but typing `Id` causes it to prompt `Id`.

It's still a pain, but I find that remembering to type `Id` saves a lot of use of the backspace key.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not best practice - as correctly suggested by Joe Stefanelli, but...

If you don't have a table in your database named **Id** you can create one and the "intelliSense" will default to this instead of IDENTITY.